# Any danger with the following override of DataSource

Tags: asp.net, data-binding

```
class MyListControl : DropDownList {
  public override object DataSource {
    get { return Helper.GetDictionary(); }
    set { }
  }
  public override string DataTextField {
    get { return "Key"; }
    set { }
  }
  public override string DataValueField {
    get { return "Value"; }
    set { }
  }
  public override void DataBind() {
    if (Helper.ConditionSatisfied) {
      base.DataBind();
    }
  }
}
```

Does ASP.NET ever need to use the set_DataSource()? And are there any references to when get_DataSource() might ever be called more than once (iterating over a collection when the iterator may not be resettable)?

Thank you.

Comment: Also, why is RequiresDataBinding not overridable?

Comment: In the future edit the question to ask additional questions, don't ask questions in the comments section.  RequiresDataBinding is protected in its base class hence not overrideable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by does it ever use set_DataSource?
Of course it does for example:

`myDropDownBox.DataSource = MyBLLayer.GetSomeDataSet(SomeParams);`

`myDropDownBox.DataBind();`

In the above example MyBLLayer is simply a static class that calls a method which returns some sort of dataset.  That dataset could be a List for example.

RequiresDataBinding is protected in the base class hence no overriding of this property.  You would not want to override this property in any case as its values are simply True or False.

Comment: I am thinking of when I have 1700 pages that I want a myDropDownBox on, I don't want 1700 Page_OnLoads that call myDropDownBox.DataSource = GetTheSameDataSet() over and over..

Comment: @maxwellb - if you really have 1700 pages with a drop down that is filled then you need to rethink your design.  The dataset should be cached once and reused across all pages so that you don't have to do that over and over.  Look into sessions / caching data.

Comment: ... and throw that dropdown into a usercontrol (with outputcaching) and insert it into 1700 pages ...